# Prevent event in over-positioned elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having some issues with this "workflow".

I have a div which contains an image being used as banner, it covers a good proportion of the screen, in this div there are also some inputs, they have attached the blur and keypress events, so whenever the user types on them and clicks out they do some AJAX work.

Now the problem is this div containing all the element simulates a click on a file input to select an image to update the banner. As the elements are inside, then when I click now on the inputs they also simulate the click on the input file.

What could I do in such case? I've tried setting the z-index for the involved elements, but that doesn't work because the main div, doesn't show nothing nor fires nothing.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]')
input.onclick = function() {
  alert('input pressed')
}
let div = document.querySelector('.main')
div.onclick = function() {
  alert('div pressed')
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-image: url('https://fthmb.tqn.com/65lNzIRNfZY4xY02D17b1RcGvso=/960x0/filters:no_upscale()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg');
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

input[name="name"] {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Type here pls">
</div>
```

This is only JS, not jQuery.

Comment: If click on input, you only want "input pressed" message, right? It shouldn't touch image?

Comment: Use this: `input.onclick = function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); /* rest here */ };`

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's right, only the input event being fired, and as the banner covers a big part, the user can just click in any other parts. Do you understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `event.stopPropagation()` for input, and it will not touch the image:

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]')
input.onclick = function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  alert('input pressed')
}
let div = document.querySelector('.main')
div.onclick = function() {
  alert('div pressed')
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-image: url('https://fthmb.tqn.com/65lNzIRNfZY4xY02D17b1RcGvso=/960x0/filters:no_upscale()/kitten-looking-at-camera-521981437-57d840213df78c583374be3b.jpg');
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
}

input[name="name"] {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <input type="text" name="name" value="Type here pls">
</div>
```

Comment: I thought by using stopPropagation I should refer the event in the div tag, now this works, waiting to accept. Thanks so much.